Algebraic formulation of statistical mechanics
Quantum Mechanics is a theory than can be formulated in many equivalent ways, and yet one of the most popular consists at its very core on representing the quantum state of a system as a vector in a Hilbert space. This formalism is interesting among many other reasons because it allows us to calculate the probability of measuring a given eigenstate of an observable in a very natural manner.
My question is simple: why don't we do the same with statistical Physics? Both theories are ergodic, heavily based on hamiltonian mechanics and we are interested in measuring the probability of a given system to be in a certain state. Could we formulate the microstate of a many-particle system using the formalism of quantum mechanics?

What you are asking for is routinely done at graduate level treatments of statistical thermodynamics. That is, the statistical thermodynamics would be rebuilt using quantum mechanics. It is only in introductory statistical thermodynamics that we entertain classical mechanical reasoning and analogies.

It's a bit more complicated. Pure states are represented by vectors in a Hilbert space representing the algebra of observables by linear maps.
A pure  state is a linear form, mapping each element of the algebra of observables, ie selfadjoint operators with real spectrum, e.g. position operators, momentum operators, spin, Hamiltonians into the real number field.
In the Schrödinger-Pauli-Dirac representation a pure state is the expectation of the variable
$$\omega_\psi(A) = \int_{\mathcal M} \psi^*(x) \ \ \text{tr}\ ( A )_x \ \psi(x) \ dVol(x)$$
A mixed state is a classical statistical mixture, drawing randomly from  the  values of pure states, weighted with a reasonable probability measure.
But dynamical systems are time dependent and the pure states follow a time evolution given by a Hamiltonian.
Mixed states are physically interesting objects only, if they do not change its density of states in time or at least slow enough to follow them macrocopically.
Since any function of the observables changes in time by the change of position and momentum variables it consists of, the density remains constant in time only if its a function of the Hamiltonian.
The same description applies to systems in classical mechanics. There is an algebra of observables, functions generated by position, momentum and spin.
A pure state is a point in the phase space, i.e. a particle at a fixed position and  a fixed momentum (think of a companioning field of observers and the fact that as an observable, momentum is not velocity).
A mixed state is the density of a probability measure over phase space. Points in phase space are moving according to the canonical time evolution fixed by a Hamilton function.
Again, physically interesting measures are time independent or slowly varying, so again the they are functions of the Hamilton function.
The fundamental difference is the algebra: the classical algebra is commutative and the pure point measures are unique. Quantum algebras are noncommutative and pure states can be choosen freely. Mostly a system is described in terms of  the eigenstates of the center of the algebra, a maximal set of commuting observables including the Hamiltonian, such that all expectation values for this set are time independent.
Both theories can be viewed together as examples of probability measures over spaces of start values, that evolve by canonical equations preserving the measure, canonical movement of prepared volume elements in phase space by the Hamilton-Jacobi PDE or densities of states evolving unitarily by $e^{i\  H \ t}$ in Hilbert space, measured at later times by the probability measure of a detector in phase space or Hilbert space.
